# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintLayout:1.1.3

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-constraintlayout

y build is failing with the error message

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.constraintlayout:constraintLayout:1.1.3

ConstraintLayout version:1.1.3
Gradle plugin version : 4.0.1
Gradle version : 6.1.1

My app_build gradle is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintLayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    // To use the Java-compatible @Experimental API annotation
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.0.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // For Lifecycle dependencies:
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - RxJava support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    // Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

}
```

My project build.gradle is

```
buildscript {
   
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // For Room Persistence Library
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The package androidx.constraintlayout does not exist in jcenter()

https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/

what you can do however,

> allprojects {
> repositories {
> mavenCentral()
> google()
> jcenter()
> maven {
> // For Room Persistence Library
> url "https://maven.google.com"
> }
> } }

Comment: I tried but I still get the messages "Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath' & Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath' & Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath'